# If I have two branches of same name on local and remote repository and both have different code, then what will happen on git fetch?

Tags: linux, git, github, command-line, version-control

I am new to git and have a very silly doubt. I have two branches of the same name on local and remote repository and both have different code. I read that `git fetch` fetches the data from remote repository to local repository and don't merge the data. So now when I do `get fetch`, changes of remote branch won't be shown in my working directory, right? And the remote branch will be in my local git repo, right?

If yes, then how do I differentiate between local and remote branch as they both have same name, so how do I checkout to remote branch? Does git give different name to remote branch? And can I also merge the changes of these two branches?

`git pull` directly merge the changes in working directory and then I have to commit them to local git repo, right?

One more question, what is the difference between checkout and checkout HEAD? I got so confused in all these git terms.

Comment: a very highly recommended reading to get a bit more into git is the "Git book" : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 4):

1. `git fetch` will only update, in your local repositories, references named `origin/<xyz>` -- the so called remote branches -- and will not mess with your actual branches. You can consider that `git fetch` is always safe to invoke.

Your local branch will be displayed as `<foo-branch>`, while the remote branch will be displayed as `origin/<foo-branch>`.

`origin/<foo-branch>` points to a valid commit, so you can `git diff <foo-branch> origin/<foo-branch>`, `git merge origin/<foo-branch>`, `git rebase origin/<foo-branch>` ...

2. `git pull` (with no extra argument) will update your local branch only if it is explicitly connected to the remote branch. You can see if it is either by running `git status` and seeing if you have a message "your branch is ahead/behind [remote branch]", or by looking at your local `.git/config` file

Comment: Thanks for answering. So HEAD always points to the last commit, right? When we do `git status`, it shows the difference between working directory and HEAD, right? I recently started reading the book you shared 2 days ago, but got confused in some points.

Comment: yes, HEAD points to the active commit. It actually is a special reference, which indicates whether your repo works with an active branch, or is in the so called "detached HEAD state". Relevant page of the git book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References (in the "Git internals" chapter)